# Diffuse lighting of objects in full shadow

Tags: 3d, rendering, lighting

So I have been working on a rendering engine for 3D scenes and have built a lighting model with directional, spot and point lights with normal, specular and shadow mapping.

In my shadow calculation, for any given light, if a fragment is found to be in shadow, then only the ambient contribution of the light is used to illuminate the fragment.

However, I have noticed in other games with global real time shadows, this must not be the case.  For example, say you have a single directional light source (ie, the sun) a large object (ie a building) and a smaller object (ie a crate).  If the crate is fully in the shadow of the building, different sides of the crate will still be shaded differently, and it won't just appear to be flatly shaded.

How is this typically achieved?  Just occlusion mapping or something else?  Is that a physically accurate model?

Comment: Ambient lighting isn't a physically accurate model, it's just to avoid having to calculate reflected light (especially diffuse). Does treating areas that the directional light can't reach as being within that light but at whatever constant would approximate your current ambient lighting, and removing the ambient entirely improve things any?